# What are the implications of a uniform p-value distribution?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared, p-value

What does a uniform p-value distribution mean? It seems so many sources say different things.

I come from a physics background, so please explain using the most basic of statistics language what the implications are for my data if this is the p-value distribution.

I was reading from two websites (noted below) that seem to state two different things for a uniform p-value distribution. Is a uniform p-value distribution good?

[p-value histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVnU.png)

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-test-your-hypothesis-using-p-value-uniformity-test-e3a43fc9d1b6

http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/interpreting-pvalue-histogram/

Comment: We are all volunteers.  Some of us find it rude for users to ask us to volunteer to first, chase three links, and then put more effort into answering a question than you put into asking it.  Besides, your one sentence of actual text is very unclear.

Comment: I have browsed your three links. One is a useless histogram with no context, the other two are 'statistical' blogs by self-proclaimed experts who do not seem to have much insight into P-values and who do not use statistical terminology with precision. It is no wonder you are confused. I recommend ignoring them. // Sometimes the distribution of P-values is uniform and sometimes not. I give illustrations of both situations in my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the test statistic is continuous, the test is exact, and the null hypothesis is true, then the P-value is uniformly distributed on the unit interval.

I will illustrate this, beginning with a sample of size $n=10$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma),$ where both parameters are unknown. We test $H_0: \mu = 0$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 0$ at level $\alpha = 0.05 = 5\%,$ using a one-sample t test. The test statistic is
$T=\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}.$

Assuming $H_0$ to be true,
$T \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1),$ Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of
freedom, where $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $S$ is the sample standard deviation.
If the observed value of $T$ is $t,$ then the P-value is $P(|T| \ge t\,|\, H_0).$
The null hypothesis is rejected if the P-value is smaller that $0.05 = 5\%.$

For example, let specific data be as sampled in R below.

```
set.seed(422)
x = rnorm(10, 0, 1); x
[1] -0.2051078  1.7241359 -1.3088931  0.3872518 -1.9000603
[6]  1.0360439  0.8976141  0.3462825  0.6213729  0.1859934

a = mean(x);  a
[1] 0.1784633
s = sd(x);  s
[1] 1.084708

t = (a - 0)/(s/sqrt(10));  t
[1] 0.5202788

pv = pt(-t,9) + 1 - pt(t,9);  pv
[1] 0.6154243
```

These computations are performed and summarized by the R procedure `t.test(x)`,
where the null value $\mu_0=0$ and a two-sided alternative are assumed unless the contrary is specified. Below is output for the sample `x` above; notice that
a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is also provided, but that is not part of
our current discussion. $H_0$ is not rejected because the P-value exceeds 5%.
That is, $\bar X = 0.1784633$
is *not significantly* different from $\mu_0 = 0.$

```
t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 0.52028, df = 9, p-value = 0.6154
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5974901  0.9544167
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.1784633
```

If we just want to see the P-value, we can use `$`-notation to show just that:

```
t.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.6154243
```

Thus, for one normal sample, we have found that the P-value is $0.6154$ and
$H_0: \mu=0$  is not rejected at the 5% level of significance. Of course, different samples from the same normal distribution, will have different values of $\bar X, S, t$ and hence different P-values.

If we want to see the P-value when the null hypothesis is *false* we can do that too.
Notice that now the P-value is smaller than 5%, so we do reject $H_0.$ More on this later.

```
t.test(x, mu=2)$p.val
[1] 0.0004871346
```

Considering the P-value as a random variable, we can ask what its distribution
is in the circumstances of using $n = 10$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ to test $H_0: \mu = 0$ against $H_a:\mu\ne 0$ at the 5% level.
Perhaps the key question is "What is the probability that $H_0$ will be rejected?"
The answer ought to be $0.05.$ But we can ask about other significance levels as well.

By simulating $m=100,000$ sample of size ten from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ we can
get $m$ P-values, and make a histogram of them to get an idea of the distribution of the P-value of the one-sample t test when $H_0$ is true.

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,0,1))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)  # aprx rejection probability
[1] 0.05093       # aprx significance level 5%
```

In the histogram below the left-most bar has 5% of the probability, and represents
the significance level of the test (the few false rejections when $H_0$ is true).

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "Uniform Dist'n of P-value when Null Hypothesis True"
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, -.1, 1.1, col="red", lwd=2, n=1001)
```

Another simulation shows the *non*-uniform distribution of the P-value when $H_0$ is false. A good test will often reject when $H_0$ is false. Accordingly, the
distribution of the P-value puts much of its probability on values near $0.$
In the samples below $\mu_0 = 1.5$ so that $H_0: \mu = 0$ is not true.
Rejection is likely.

```
set.seed(1235)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10, 1.5, 1))$p.val)  # Ho false
mean(pv <= 0.05)  # aprx rejection probability
[1] 0.98708       # aprx power 99% of test against alternative 2
```

[image]

```
hdr = "Non-Uniform Dist'n of P-value when Null Hypothesis False"
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

Finally, when the test statistic is discrete or the test is approximate,
the distribution of the P-value will not necessarily be unifor--even when
$H_0$ is true. However, one can hope that the probability below 0.05 is about 0.05.
Here is an example, showing the distribution of the Wilcoxon signed rank test
for a small samples from the standard normal distribution.

```
set.seed(1776)
pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rnorm(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04813  # signif level near 5%
```

[image]

```
hdr = "Non-Uniform Dist'n of P-value of Wilcoxon SR Test: Null True"
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, -.1, 1.1, col="red", lwd=2, n=1001)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am still unsure what this means for my data.

I am generating triangularly distributed random numbers and comparing them to the theoretical results expected from this distribution. Each time I run this I calculate a chi-squared value and p-value (using chisq.test() in R). I then run this 100 times and plot a histogram of the p-values. 
In this case, what would the null hypothesis be? And is the test statistic continuous, and the test exact? Would the null hypothesis be that the triangularly distributed random numbers are in fact triangularly distributed?

Comment: Chi-sq test is not exact, and because it depends on counts it is discrete at some level, so you should not expect its P-value under $H_0$ to be exactly uniform. // YES to the 2nd question about the null hypothesis.